# SQL Statement LEFT JOIN cant get result i looking for

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello i have this SQL below but i am having a problem with it i keep the Attendance records in the Attendance Table and the notes in the StaffComments Table but i also have a table ContractorsComments witch uses the same attendance table and the NotesID column in some cases has doubled up

contractors have different PRN to Staff i tried to use

WHERE dbo.StaffComments.PRN = 15458 AND dbo.Attendance.PRN = 15458

but this cause it to only show records where is found a match in both tables

i need the SQL to show all Notes in the dbo.StaffComments table but only records with the SAME PRN in the dbo.Attendance

```
 SELECT Comments, PRN, id, DateMade, UserID, Reason, EventDate, AttendanceID, Sdate, Edate
        FROM ( 
        SELECT dbo.StaffComments.Comments, dbo.StaffComments.PRN, dbo.StaffComments.id, dbo.StaffComments.DateMade, dbo.StaffComments.UserID, dbo.StaffComments.Reason, 
        dbo.StaffComments.EventDate, dbo.Attendance.id AS AttendanceID, dbo.Attendance.Sdate, dbo.Attendance.Edate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.StaffComments.ID DESC) AS RowNum 
        FROM dbo.StaffComments 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Attendance
        ON dbo.StaffComments.id = dbo.Attendance.NoteID     
        WHERE dbo.StaffComments.PRN = 15458  
        ) AS notes 
        WHERE notes.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ON clause to JOIN on PRN

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Attendance
        ON dbo.StaffComments.id = dbo.Attendance.NoteID     
        AND dbo.StaffComments.PRN = dbo.Attendance.PRN 
        WHERE dbo.StaffComments.PRN = 15458
```

Your updated query will look like this:

```
SELECT Comments, PRN, id, DateMade, UserID, Reason, EventDate, AttendanceID, Sdate, Edate
        FROM ( 
        SELECT dbo.StaffComments.Comments, dbo.StaffComments.PRN, dbo.StaffComments.id, dbo.StaffComments.DateMade, dbo.StaffComments.UserID, dbo.StaffComments.Reason, 
        dbo.StaffComments.EventDate, dbo.Attendance.id AS AttendanceID, dbo.Attendance.Sdate, dbo.Attendance.Edate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.StaffComments.ID DESC) AS RowNum 
        FROM dbo.StaffComments 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Attendance
        ON dbo.StaffComments.id = dbo.Attendance.NoteID
        AND dbo.StaffComments.PRN = dbo.Attendance.PRN 
        WHERE dbo.StaffComments.PRN = 15458  
        ) AS notes 
        WHERE notes.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you joining on staffcomments.id and attendance.noteid?

You need to join on PRN like you did before, but with an outer join.

```
SELECT Comments, PRN, id, DateMade, UserID, Reason, EventDate, AttendanceID, Sdate, Edate
        FROM ( 
        SELECT dbo.StaffComments.Comments, dbo.StaffComments.PRN, dbo.StaffComments.id, dbo.StaffComments.DateMade, dbo.StaffComments.UserID, dbo.StaffComments.Reason, 
        dbo.StaffComments.EventDate, dbo.Attendance.id AS AttendanceID, dbo.Attendance.Sdate, dbo.Attendance.Edate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.StaffComments.ID DESC) AS RowNum 
        FROM dbo.StaffComments 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Attendance
        ON dbo.StaffComments.PRN = dbo.Attendance.PRN    
        WHERE dbo.StaffComments.PRN = 15458  
        ) AS notes 
        WHERE notes.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Comment: i have tried your code but i still only get rows the are in both dbo.StaffComments and dbo.Attendance

hang on sorry from what i can see there is 1 record showing now form the dbo.StaffComments and matched it 60 records in the dbo.Attendance table